# Winforms : How to bind the Checkbox item of a CheckedListBox with databinding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a databinded checkedlistbox in one form and I would like to know if it is even possible to databind the check box of each list box item with a certain property of an object.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Edit : Perhaps my question was misinterpreted.

I would like to know if it is possible to databind the checkbox for each Item of CheckedListBox. I know how to databind to a source and how to programatically change the entries by iterating through the itmes. What I don't know is if it is possible to have a class
which implements INotifyPropertyChanged so that when a "CheckedState" property changes the CheckedListBox updates itself.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

According to Samich's answer, Here is a full example, the binding source is an `Object`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<randomClass> lst = new List<randomClass>();

            lst.Add(new randomClass());
            lst.Add(new randomClass());
            lst.Add(new randomClass());
            lst.Add(new randomClass());
            lst.Add(new randomClass());
            lst.Add(new randomClass());

            ((ListBox)this.checkedListBox1).DataSource = lst;
            ((ListBox)this.checkedListBox1).DisplayMember = "Name";
            ((ListBox)this.checkedListBox1).ValueMember = "IsChecked";


            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                randomClass obj = (randomClass)checkedListBox1.Items[i];
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, obj.IsChecked);
            }
        }
    }

    public class randomClass
    {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public randomClass()
        {
            this.IsChecked = true;
            Name = "name1";
        }
    }
```

`randomClass` is for demonstration purposes

Comment: I am already doing this. I am coming from WPF where I used to bind everything to properties and I don't seem to be able to add a binding to the checkListBox."isChecked" property. I know the property does not exist so how could we bind to it? I just want to make sure there is not a hidden trick which enables us to do this.

Comment: DisplayMember binds but ValueMember does not!?! Does not make sense. I used your for loop with success. thanks

Comment: Of course this is not __real two-way__ databinding.

Comment: Shouldn't `ValueMember` be bound to an Id?

Comment: hint : Make sure your DataSource is placed first before DisplayMember =(The Description/data of your data column) and ValueMember  =(the Id of your data column)

Answer (score 7):

You can find answer here: [Using datasource with CheckBoxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777268/using-datasource-with-checkboxlist)

```
var checkBoxList = (ListBox)MyCheckBoxList;
checkBoxList.DataSource = dataSource;
checkBoxList.DisplayMember = "name";
checkBoxList.ValueMember = "enabled";
```

Make sure that the `ValueMember` is of type `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

I just got how to databind a table in sql to a checkboxlist without stress. I am more than excited to share it.
I added them manually...

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=MICMIKE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Enterprise;Integrated Security=True";
        conn.Open();
        string query = "Select Position from Position";// position column from position table
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            string myItem = dr["Position"].ToString();
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(myItem, true);//true means check the items. use false if you don't want to check the items or simply .....Items.Add(myItem);
        }
```

To Access the items checked in the checklistbox,  use

```
        foreach(object item in Checkedlistbox1.CheckedItems)
        {
             string itemchecked = item.ToString();
             MessageBox.Show(itemchecked);// This will show all the checked items in the checklistbox.
        }
```

It is really working. I just got it now.
I hope you like it!