# Dynamic binding to CheckedListBox using entity model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I am using `CheckedListBox` control in windows forms. I need to bind that `CheckedListBox` Dynamically using entity model.

**My Query:**

```
private void BindTax()
        {
            try
            {
                eTax Tax = new eTax();
                cTax cTax= new cTax();
                List<eTax> ObjTax = cTax.GetTax(eGEntities);
                Tax.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32("-1");
                Tax.CategoryName = "--Select--";
                ObjTax.Insert(0, Tax);
                foreach (eTax item in ObjTax)
                {
                    lstchkTax.Items.Add(item.TaxName);

                }                
           }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
```

I am getting `Dispayname` but I'm not getting the `selectedValue`. I am not finding the data source property for this control. Please tell me How can I do this?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast it to a ListBox for the binding to work. I'm not sure why.  The code would look like this...

```
((ListBox)lstchkTax).DataSource=ObjTax;
((ListBox)lstchkTax).DisplayMember="CategoryName";
((ListBox)lstchkTax).ValueMember="CategoryId";
```

A longer example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7485900/7495).