# CheckedListBox and List of Object's list

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, bindinglist

I needed to give a name to a list, as well as implementing one or two useful methods in addition. So this is my program architecture:

```
public class A 
{
    public void Method1()
    {
    ...
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
    ...
    }
}

public class B : List<A>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
    ...
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

And then, in my mainform, I'm creating and instancing:

```
BindingList<B> MyList = new BindingList<B> MyList();
```

To use it with a CheckedListBox, I'm using:

```
MyListBox.DataSource = MyList;
```

And then when I'm adding a new element to MyList, I've got the wrong text in the CheckedListBox. Indeed, it shows just one string "(Collection)", even if I have more than one item in MyList
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not binding the List to your DataSource correctly.

Instead of passing in the list, you could add them like the first answer in [Using datasource with CheckBoxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777268/using-datasource-with-checkboxlist)

```
foreach (var item in MyList)
    MyListBox.Items.Add(item.WhateverFieldYouWantToBind, false); // second param is whether it's checked or not
```